# How to make unequal sine wave?

Tags: r, math

I have „newbie” question related to basic math. I am trying to make sine wave with “unequal radians” (at least I believe this is what I am trying to do). In other words: I need function that for first couple periods (x) is “faster” and gradually slows down (“cycles” are wider/longer) as x approaches infinity. Here is code and sketch of what I am trying to do:

```
x <- seq(1, 30, by=0.1)  # my x

z <- ifelse(x <= 10, 3, ifelse(x <= 20, 2, 1))  # discrete value to modify x

y <- sin(z*x)  # my y(x)

plot(y, type="l")  # plot y(x)
```

and sketch (result of `plot`):

[image]

Ignore the “double peak” and other distortions, they are result of fact that `z` is discrete variable. I would like to make `z` continuous and make each cycle to widen smoothly. What mathematical function should I use here? I tried damped sine wave but this is not quite what I am going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct transcription from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp#Types) linked by @keziah: here's a function

```
chirp <- function(t,phi0=0,f0=1,k=1) sin(phi0 + 2*pi*(f0*t+k*t^2/2))
```

- phi0 is the initial phase
- k is the rate of frequency change or chirpyness.
- f0 is the initial frequency

```
 par(las=1,bty="l",mfrow=c(1,2))
 curve(chirp(x),from=0,to=5,n=501)
 curve(chirp(x,k=-1,f0=5),from=0,to=5,n=501)
```

[image]

Comment: This is basically what I was going for. Although, I have one problem, I was going to use it for loop: for function of iteration counts(`n`) and every time when function value is equal to 0 (f(n)=0) to make something happened. That is why I needed it to slow down in time. I want  this “something” happen more often at the beginning of the process (loop) and less often as it progresses. How do I approach it when my iteration count is 1000 for example? (`n=1000`).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a full answer, as I can't give you code off the top of my head, but what you're looking for here is a chirp. There are a few different types of chirp, depending on the rate of change of phase that you want, but I'm guessing you probably want a linear chirp [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp#Types)

R may well have a function/module that can provide this already.